# Proper way to set array values in C with doubling scheme?

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list

I am reading in a file of locations with coordinates, city names and country names. Currently I am just testing to see if i can store the first element of each line in my array. The fallowing is a sample of the file i am reading in:

```
Durban, South Africa
29 53 S
30 53 E
```

The trouble i am having is that when I try to store the first element of each line in my array the same value gets stored for every element in the array. Code i have so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "kml.h"

#define LEN 128

struct quard_t {
        char *city;
        char *state;
        char *country;
        int longitude;
        int latitude;

};

struct data_t {
        int nval;
        int max;
        struct quard_t *data;
};

enum {INIT = 1, GROW = 2};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        char buf[LEN];
        char *str;
        int cnt = 0;
        FILE *in = fopen(argv[1], "r") ;
        struct data_t *data = malloc(sizeof(struct data_t));
        data->nval = INIT;
        data->max = INIT;
        data->data = NULL;

        while (fgets(buf, LEN, in)) {
                if (data->nval > data->max){
                        data->data = realloc(data->data, GROW * data->max *sizeof(struct quard_t));
                        data->max = GROW * data->max;
                }
                else if (data->data == NULL)
                        data->data = malloc(INIT * sizeof(struct quard_t));

                str = strtok(buf, " ");
                data->data[cnt].city = str;
                cnt++;
        }

        int i = 0;
        for ( ; i < cnt; i++ ){
               printf("%d: %s\n", i, data->data[i].city);
        }

        fclose(in);
        return 0;
}
```

The fallowing is the output i am getting, the numbers being the index of the array and everything after being what is stored in the array:

```
190: 30
191: 30
192: 30
193: 30
194: 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are assigning a value to `city`:

```
data->data[cnt].city = str;
```

All you are doing is assigning a pointer, not the actual data currently stored in `str`. So when you overwrite `str` later, `city` is pointing to the latest value of `str`. To fix this you need to allocate space for `city` when you allocate space for the `quard_t` structure. Then copy the string into this new buffer using `strcpy`. You'll have to do the same for the `state` and `country` fields.

Also, your `data` structure isn't really a linked list. You've really just created your own quasi-vector structure. A true linked list has the data members plus a pointer to the structure itself. I suggest you do a little research on linked list implementations.